# multiple checkbox values into same sql column?

Tags: php, sql

I'm looking for a simple solution to inserting multiple checkbox selections into a single database column. If user selects 3 x l_comp checkboxes - the database should reflect "result, result, result".. the commas would be nice but are not neccessary.
As it is, if one checkbox is selected, the information will insert as it should. If multiple are selected, only the last one will be inserted into the DB. Everything else is working fine, but these darned checkboxes!

I know i'm vulnerable to sql-injection

My code:

```
<?php
// Initialize the session
session_start();

// Include config file
require_once "assets/scripts/config.php";

$param_uniqid = $_SESSION['uniqid']; 
$param_company = $_SESSION['company'];  
$param_vat = $_SESSION['vat']; 
$param_username = $_SESSION['username']; 

// Check if the user is logged in, if not then redirect him 
to login page
if(!isset($_SESSION["loggedin"]) || $_SESSION["loggedin"] 
!== true){
header("location: login.php");
exit;
}

// Define variables and initialize with empty values
$l_comp = $user = $car = $uniqid = $company = $vat = 
$username = "";
$l_comp_err = $user_err = $car_err = $uniqid_err = "";

// Processing form data when form is submitted
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){

// Validate l_comp
$input_l_comp = trim($_POST["l_comp"]);
if(empty($input_l_comp)){
    $l_comp_err = "Venligst indtast leasingselskab.";
} elseif(!filter_var($input_l_comp, FILTER_VALIDATE_REGEXP, 
array("options"=>array("regexp"=>"/^[0-9a-åA-Å+&@#\/%-? 
=~_|!:,.;\s]+$/")))){
    $l_comp_err = "Leasingselskab er ikke korrekt.";
} else{
    $l_comp = $input_l_comp;
} 

// Validate user
$input_user = trim($_POST["user"]);
if(empty($input_user)){
    $user_err = "Venligst indtast en bruger.";
} elseif(!filter_var($input_user, FILTER_VALIDATE_REGEXP, 
array("options"=>array("regexp"=>"/^[0-9a-åA-Å\s]+$/")))){
    $user_err = "Bruger er ikke korrekt.";
} else{
    $user = $input_user;
}

// Validate car
$input_car = trim($_POST["car"]);
if(empty($input_car)){
    $car_err = "Venligst indtast bilinformationer.";
} elseif(!filter_var($input_car, FILTER_VALIDATE_REGEXP, 
array("options"=>array("regexp"=>"/^[0-9a-åA-Å+&@#\/%-? 
=~_|!:,.;\s]+$/")))){
    $car_err = "Bil er ikke korrekt.";
} else{
    $car = $input_car;
}

// Validate uniqid
$input_uniqid = trim($_POST["uniqid"]);
if(empty($input_uniqid)){
    $uniqid_err = "Venligst indtast uniqid.";
} elseif(!filter_var($input_uniqid, FILTER_VALIDATE_REGEXP, array("options"=>array("regexp"=>"/^[0-9a-åA-Å+&@#\/%-?=~_|!:,.;\s]+$/")))){
    $uniqid_err = "Uniqid er ikke korrekt.";
} else{
    $uniqid = $input_uniqid;
}

// Check input errors before inserting in database
if(empty($l_comp_err) && empty($user_err) && empty($car_err) 
&& empty($uniqid_err)){
    // Prepare an insert statement
    $sql = "INSERT INTO offer_requests_test (l_comp, user, 
car, uniqid, company, vat, username) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, 
?, ?)";
     
    if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, $sql)){
        // Bind variables to the prepared statement as 
parameters
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "sssssss", 
$param_l_comp, $param_user, $param_car, $param_uniqid, 
$param_company, $param_vat, $param_username);
        
        // Set parameters
        $param_l_comp = $l_comp;
        $param_user = $user;
        $param_car = $car;
        $param_uniqid = $uniqid;
        
        // Attempt to execute the prepared statement
        if(mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)){
            // Records created successfully. Redirect to 
landing page
            header("location: /offer_requests_test");
            exit();
        } else{
            echo "Something went wrong. Please try again 
later.";
        }
    }
}
}

?>

<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<html>
<head>
    <title>Fleets - få op til 3 tilbud på jeres næste 
leasingbil</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/main.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.css">
</head>
<body class="subpage">

    <!-- Header -->
        <header id="header">
            <div class="logo"><a href="index.html">Fleets.dk <span>3 tilbud på leasingbil</span></a></div>
            <a href="assets/scripts/logout.php" class="code">LOG UD</a>
        </header>

<!-- content -->
        <div class="box">
            <div class="inner">
                <div class="content">
                        <h4>Hej, <b><?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SESSION["name"]); ?></b>.</h4>

                    <hr />

                    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                      <li role="presentation"><a href="/welcome">Profil</a></li>
                      <li role="presentation"><a href="/cars_employees">Biler</a></li>
                      <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="offer_requests">Tilbud</a></li>
                      <li role="presentation"><a href="/l_contacts">Kontakter</a></li>
                    </ul>
                        
                        <div class="table-wrapper">
                        <h4 class="pull-left">Oprettede tilbud</h4>
                        
                                <table>
                                    <tbody>
                                        <tr>
                                            <th class="hidden"><b>#</b></th>
                                            <th><b>Bil</b></th>
                                            <th><b>Bruger</b></th>
                        <?php
                        // Include config file
                        require_once "assets/scripts/config.php";
                        
                        // Attempt select query execution
                         $sql = "SELECT * FROM offer_requests_test WHERE username = '" . ($_SESSION["username"]) . "'";
                        if($result = mysqli_query($link, $sql)){
                            if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){

                                            echo "<th></th>";
                                            echo "<th></th>";
                                            echo "<th></th>";
                                        echo "</tr>";
                                    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
                                        echo "<tr>";
                                            echo "<th class='hidden'>" . $row['uniqid'] . "</th>";
                                            echo "<th>" . $row['car'] . "</th>";
                                            echo "<th>" . $row['user'] . "</th>";
                                            echo "<th>";
                                                echo "<a href='read_request.php?uniqid=". $row['uniqid'] ."' title='View Record' data-toggle='tooltip'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open'></span></a>";
                                            echo "</th>";
                                            echo "<th>";
                                                echo "<a href='update_request.php?uniqid=". $row['uniqid'] ."' title='Update Record' data-toggle='tooltip'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-pencil'></span></a>";
                                            echo "</th>";
                                            echo "<th>";
                                                echo "<a href='delete_request.php?uniqid=". $row['uniqid'] ."' title='Delete Record' data-toggle='tooltip'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-trash'></span></a>";
                                            echo "</th>";
                                        echo "</tr>";
                                    }
                                // Free result set
                                mysqli_free_result($result);
                            } else{
                                echo "</br></br><p><b><i>Ingen informationer fundet.</i></b></p>";
                            }
                        } else{
                            echo "ERROR: Was not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($link);
                        }
                                             echo "</tbody>";                            
                                echo "</table>";
                        ?>
                        <p>
                            <div href="" class="button alt small" onclick="hideCreate()">OPRET NYT TILBUD</div>
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    <!-- create -->
        <div class="box">
            <div class="inner">
                <div class="content">  
                    <div id="create">    
                            <h4>1 - udfyld formularen</h4>
                                <form action="" method="post">
                                        <div class="6u 12u$(xsmall) <?php echo (!empty($car_err)) ? 'has-error' : ''; ?>">
                                            <label>Bil</label>
                                            <input type="text" name="car" class="6u 12u$(xsmall)" value="<?php echo $car; ?>">
                                            <span class="help-block"><?php echo $car_err;?></span>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="6u 12u$(xsmall) <?php echo (!empty($user_err)) ? 'has-error' : ''; ?>">
                                            <label>Bruger</label>
                                            <input type="text" name="user" class="6u 12u$(xsmall)" value="<?php echo $user; ?>">
                                            <span class="help-block"><?php echo $user_err;?></span>
                                        </div>
                                            <input type="hidden" name="company" value="<?php echo $company; ?>">
                                            <input type="hidden" name="vat" value="<?php echo $vat; ?>">
                                            <input type="hidden" name="username" value="<?php echo $username; ?>">
                                            <input type="hidden" name="uniqid" value="<?php echo uniqid(); ?>" /></input>
                                            </br></br>                                        

</br></br><div class="table-wrapper">
<h4 class="pull-left">2 - vælg op til tre leasingselskaber</h4></br></br>

        <table>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <th class="hidden"><b>#</b></th>
                    <th><b>Vælg</b></th>                                             

                    <?php
                        // Include config file
                        require_once "assets/scripts/config.php";
                        
                        // Attempt select query execution
                         $sql = "SELECT l_comp FROM l_comp";
                        if($result = mysqli_query($link, $sql)){
                            if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){

                                            echo "<th><b>Leasingselskab</b></th>";
                                            echo "<th></th>";
                                        echo "</tr>";
                                    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
                                        echo "<tr>";
                                            echo "<th>";

                                                echo "<div class='6u 12u$(xsmall) <?php echo (!empty(" . $l_comp_err . ")) ? 'has-error' : ''; ?> 
                                                        <input type='checkbox' id='" . $row['l_comp'] . "' name='l_comp' value='" . $row['l_comp'] . "'>
                                                        <label for='" . $row['l_comp'] . "'></label>
                                                        <span class='help-block'><?php echo " . $l_comp_err. ";?></span>  
                                                     ";

                                            echo "</th>";
                                            echo "<th>" . $row['l_comp'] . "</th>";
                                        echo "</tr>";
                                    }
                                // Free result set
                                mysqli_free_result($result);
                            } else{
                                echo "</br></br><p><b><i>Ingen informationer fundet.</i></b></p>";
                            }
                        } else{
                            echo "ERROR: Was not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($link);
                        }
                                             echo "</tbody>";                            
                                echo "</table>";
                    ?>

                    </br></br>
                    <input type="submit" class="button alt small" value="OPRET TILBUDSKLADE">
                    <a href="/offer_requests_test" class="button alt small">FORTRYD</a>

                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Footer -->
        <footer id="footer" class="wrapper">
            <div class="inner">
                <div class="copyright">
                    &copy; Fleets.dk - for virksomheder </br> 
                    <a href="mailto: kontakt@fleets.dk">KONTAKT OS</a> 
                </div>
            </div>
        </footer>

    <!-- Scripts -->
        <script src="assets/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="assets/js/jquery.scrolly.min.js"></script>
        <script src="assets/js/jquery.scrollex.min.js"></script>
        <script src="assets/js/skel.min.js"></script>
        <script src="assets/js/util.js"></script>
        <script src="assets/js/main.js"></script>
        <script src="assets/js/overlay_create.js"></script>
        <script src="assets/js/overlay_login.js"></script>

</body>
```

Comment: `multiple checkbox selections into a single database column.`...is a basic database design flaw, which will leave your data denormalised and hard to query afterwards. Don't do it. Learn how to normalise your schema correctly instead. You'll need a second table for this

Comment: You could use a _flags_-style approach to store the checkbox values in a numeric column, where each bit represents a different checkbox. I've done this before to store multiple boolean values in a single column

Comment: @ADyson - So to understand you suggestion... i would have separate tables for each checkbox?

Comment: @Martin - "flags-style approach"?

Comment: @MortenBrochner not necessarily no, depends what the data is. More like, a separate table so you can store multiple values for that field, for each record in the original table. Standard one-to-many relationship

Comment: I think @Martin means storing the three values as a single string like one of these: `TTF`, `YYN` or `110`, with each position representing one of the checkboxes. The last is also easily convertable into a "bitwise" datastorage. Many RDBMSs have special functionality to handle bitwise operations. This page looks like a useful intro to the idea: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1218/sql-server-bitwise-operators-to-store-multiple-values-in-one-column/

Comment: @SteveLovell Thank you, exactly what I was intending.  I meant to look up a suitable article like this one but got distracted before I had a chance

Comment: Perfect @Martin - this is the way to go... thx!!